# Status bar in bash

Tags: bash, shell, statusbar

Firstly, Thanks everyone for all your help. I can see the successful completion of my project in couple of days..

I need to know how to put a status bar in Shell Script, something like this.

```
No_of_files=55
index=0

while [ $index -lt $No_of_files ]
do
     echo -en "$index of $No_of_Files Completed"
     index=$((index + 1))
done
```

Expected Result :
1 of 55 Completed
2 of 55 Completed

Every iteration, index should be replaced but not other characters.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: If an answer works for you, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer. This will go a long way in your ability to get more detailed answers in the future and will help those who happen upon this with the same question.

Comment: I am new to this forum and amazed how quick people have been forthcoming to help each other.. Thanks for pointing it out, well again.. 
kiran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can print `\r` to go back to the beginning of the line, so that you can overwrite the last thing printed with a new message:

```
for (( I=0 ; I < 10 ; I++ )); do
   echo -en "\r$I of 10 completed"
   sleep 1
done
echo
```

This looks like the just the `$I` number would be changing.

Comment: +1 and deleted my answer because I like `\r` better than `tput hpa 0` since I'm sure its more portable.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to increment the $index variable. `((index++))`. You can see [here](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html) also for a script to do progress bar

here's a Poor man's version

```
No_of_files=55
index=0

while [ $index -lt $No_of_files ]
do
     echo -ne "\r$index of $No_of_files Completed"
     ((index++))
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I would not recommend using `clear` because that will wipe out any other sort of screen info that you may possibly want or add in the future. `tput hpa 0` or even echoing out a bunch of `\b` is a better way to go.